# "Abusive" vs "invective" vs "vituperative"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the different between *abusive*, *invective* and *vituperative*? In the following definitions from Oxford, the last two both contain *abusive*, which makes me hard to distinguish them.

> **Abusive**: Extremely offensive and insulting.
>
> **Invective**: Insulting, abusive, or highly critical language
>
> **Vituperative**: Bitter and abusive

The only thing I can say about *invective* is that it is used only in words, not actions.

Comment: *vituperative* ? I learned a new word today.

Comment: *Vituperative* is an adjective (the other two are nouns). The related nouns are *vituperation* and *vituperativeness*.

Comment: @ErikKowal oops, my glitch. I mean *abusive*. Do we have an adjective for *invective*?

Comment: According to my *Chambers 20th Century Dictionary*, **invective** is also an adjective with the meanings 'railing; abusive; satirical' (however, I've never encountered it as anything other than a noun).

Comment: *Invective:*  (necessarily) of language. *Vituperative:*  abusive **plus** bitter. HTH.

Comment: From etymonline: vituperation (n.) mid-15c., but rare before early 19c., from Latin *vituperationem* (nominative vituperatio) "blame, a blaming, censuring," from past participle stem of *vituperare* "disparage, find fault with," from *vitiperos* "having faults," from vitium "fault, defect" (see *vice* (n.1)) + *parare* "prepare, provide, procure" (see pare). *Vituperatio* was stronger than either Latin *reprehension* or Modern English vituperation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to tell the last two apart is that, these days, "invective" is almost always used as a noun (as it is in the definition you cited). In older days it apparently was used as an adjective.

"Vituperative" is always an adjective. As commenters have noted, the noun form is "vituperation". One very rarely hears either spoken. Few Americans know these, and fewer still are willing to speak such a five-syllable word in public for fear of being thought erudite or even pedantic.

You could refer to a person as "abusive", but without further clarification that could mean physically abusive, verbally abusive or both. You could say he used abusive language. Anyone would know what you meant.

Invective is a good word to describe so-called rational arguments from supposedly intelligent people that are really disguised ad hominem remarks. William Buckley, for instance, was a master of this, disguising truly offensive views in flowery sesquipedalianism.